# How can I give full width of this element?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/functionmentes/

There is a div with the color `#D9D9D9`

Code of CSS:

```css
#full_bar {
  background: #D9D9D9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I want my div to be the full-width site and glued to the footer.

How can I make this?

I use a theme in WordPress.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a full width bar...then make it a `section` just like all the other full width sections you have on the current site. Close of the existing section, add this new full width one and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Making the position fixed, will ensure that it will follow the user as they scroll up and down your website.

```css
#full_bar {
  background: #d9d9d9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position:absolute; left: 0;` to the css, the bar will more or less do what you're trying to do, but it's a dirty hack.

The real problem is that you're adding your 'full_bar' in the wrong place (inside a div which restricts the width). Personally I would opt for placing the full-bar in your `<footer>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your gray bar outside the section, between the section and the footer, or on the footer on HTML.

But if you want a CSS solution, you need to put your section parent to position relative and set your gray bar on absolute bottom with full width:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px; // Your bar height
}
    
#full_bar {
  background: #D9D9D9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `#full_bar` inside `class="container"`. container is the parent of div id #`full_bar`, that's why its not taking full width.
Do your code outside contaner class and you can see the changes.

See the attachment, i think you want this as per i understand your question.

[image]